# Combining two sentences into one

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

I wonder whether the below sentence makes sense.

---

I'm finding very hard to make it a habit to do things I'm reluctant that are considered good.

---

What I want to say is 
1) I'm finding very hard to make it a habit to do things that are considered good.
2) Those good things are something I'm not very interested or I'm reluctant to work on (e.g. doing regular exercise, eating healthy, reading more books, being more social, etc).

I'd like to say it in a single sentence, without breaking into two sentences. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your sentence is crowded and that makes it awkward. Replace the 'make it' with 'develop' and drop the 'considered' -- then it can be somewhat simplified as "I am finding it very hard to *develop* some good habits [that] I am reluctant to work on." 'That' is optional here and is implied even if not written.

Comment: A friendly word of warning here: English has these wonderful things called ***demonstrative determiners***, so you should use them.  *Below* makes for a poor adjective—notice that *“How many below sentences are there?”* is ungrammatical. Your use of “the below”, though common in various Asian English dialects, is regularly replaced by other words elsewhere, as it sounds unnaturally stilted.  Saying "the below” sounds bad to many and perhaps most native speakers, who never reach for it when “this/these/that/those” would do, nor even when “the following” would do.

Comment: Just to say *the below sentence* sounds terrible. Use *the sentence below*.

Comment: 'I find discipline difficult.' Although this is hardly worth saying.

Comment: Thank you @tchrist for enlightening me! I guess I have a tendency to incorrectly use "the below"...

Comment: Thank you @EnglishStudent, "I am finding it very hard to develop some good habits [that] I am reluctant to work on." sounds perfect to me!

Comment: Glad to help you @Joey sort it out, but it is a matter of READING a lot of good English. One of the best places to read English online is Wikipedia, which will educate you at the same time: however it is a very neutral language. Reading a lot of good articles written by native English speakers on various subjects at different websites will enrich your vocabulary and give you a natural feel for syntax and grammar. If you like reading fiction or nonfiction a huge collection of books is available for reading online at Open Library -- all of that reading will soon make your English sentences flow!

Comment: Did I forget to tell you, @Joey that some of the best idiomatic English by native and non-native speakers is written right here, in answers and comments to thousands of questions about grammar and usage, at English.StackExchange.com! So keep asking questions and keep reading. Note 2: the formally correct way of combining your sentences "I am finding it very hard to develop some good habits" and "I am reluctant to work on them"  is, *'I am finding it very hard to develop some good habits **because** I am reluctant to work on them.'*

Comment: @Joey You are very welcome. Just remember that [Rome wasn't built in a day,](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22Rome+wasn%27t+built+in+a+day%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=oQ9jWcTMIY_j8wenjKy4CQ) but once built, became great forever. If you like reading and English, you will do very well indeed. Keep participating actively at English.StackExchange.com!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities include:

- I’m finding it hard to overcome my reluctance
  to do things that are good for me.
- I’m finding it hard to overcome my reluctance
  to form a habit of doing things that are good for me.
- I’m finding it hard to overcome my reluctance
  to do things that are good for me, especially on a frequent basis.
- I’m finding it hard to overcome my reluctance
  to do things that are good for me, especially habitually.
- I’m finding it hard to do things that I don’t like to do,
  even if they’re good for me.
                      (or “that I don’t enjoy [doing]”)
- I’m finding it hard to form a habit of doing things that I don’t like to do,
  even if they’re good for me.
- I’m finding it hard to do things that are good for me,
  if I don’t like to do them.
                      (or “if I don’t enjoy [doing] them”)
- I’m finding it hard to form a habit of doing things that are good for me,
  if I don’t like to do them.

Replace “good for me” as needed
(e.g., with “good for society” or “good for the community”, etc.)

Comment: Thank you @scott, I like the first one, short and concise!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your sentence is that "I'm reluctant" lacks context and needs extrapolation. The reluctance might refer to your habit or to the consideration of goodness, and only your comment made it clear.

How about this: "I'm finding it very hard to make it a habit to do things that are considered good when I only reluctantly agree."

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding it very hard to make it a habit to do things that are considered good, but I'm reluctant to do.

(This is not most fluent, clear sentence. I wanted to make only minimal changes to your original, not a major editing job.)